# Error: Cannot find symbol import org.opencv.BuildConfig; Android studio

Tags: java, opencv

I trying to import openCV into android studio. I am using 4.6 and Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 and I am getting following error:

error: cannot find symbol
import org.opencv.BuildConfig;
^
symbol:   class BuildConfig
location: package org.opencv

I am not sure how to fix this because I cannot find information on org.opencv.BuildConfig anywhere.

Here is my build.gradle (:openCV)

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

def openCVersionName = "4.6.0"
def openCVersionCode = ((4 * 100 + 6) * 100 + 0) * 10 + 0

println "OpenCV: " +openCVersionName + " " + project.buildscript.sourceFile

android {
    buildFeatures {
        aidl true
    }

    compileSdkVersion 33

    namespace 'org.opencv'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33

        versionCode openCVersionCode
        versionName openCVersionName

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                targets "opencv_jni_shared"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packagingOptions {
                doNotStrip '**/*.so'  // controlled by OpenCV CMake scripts
            }
        }
        release {
            packagingOptions {
                doNotStrip '**/*.so'  // controlled by OpenCV CMake scripts
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['native/libs']
            java.srcDirs = ['java/src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['java/src']
            res.srcDirs = ['java/res']
            manifest.srcFile 'java/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path (project.projectDir.toString() + '/libcxx_helper/CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

I ran into a few issues. The first was that the package was defined in the AndroidManifest file of the openCV SDK which is now deprecated so I defined `namespace 'org.opencv'` in the build.gradle (openCV). Then I had to set `buildFeatures { aidl true }` to true in build.gradle files for the app and openCV. That solved my other issues but now I do not know how to fix the BuildConfig issues.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same thing and tried to create a BuildConfig.java in org/opencv with code I found online:

```
package org.opencv;

public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME = "org.opencv";
  /**
   * @deprecated APPLICATION_ID is misleading in libraries. For the library package name use LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME
   */
  @Deprecated
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "org.opencv";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 4100;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "4.1.0";
}
```

I changed VERSION_CODE to 406000 and VERSION_NAME to "4.6.0" and it compiles without problems.
This is not the solution but it works for me :)

Comment: Noted! I will give it a shot. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

In the `build.gradle` file of the opencv module, add this:

```
buildFeatures{
    aidl true
    buildConfig true
}
```

Now, the `BuildConfig` is generated for you.

Answer (score 1):

Open Gradle `Scripts/gradle.properties` (Project Properties) and look near the bottom line.
If you see the below is not there, add it.

```
"android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true"
```

Then `"org.opencv.BuildConfig"` will be generated automatically at build time.